# Are all outcomes equally likely in my probability game?

Tags: probability

Colour burst is a probability game. A spinner is first spun, and the objective of the game is popping the balloon containing confetti of the colour the spinner landed on.

You have a 2/5=¼ (0.4/40%/2:5) chance of getting each colour on the spinner and a ⅛(0.125/12.5%/1:8) chance of landing on each colour. There are 12 balloons on the board and 3 balloons contain each of the colours. You have a 3/12=¼ (0.25/25%/3:12) chance of getting a balloon that contain the correct coloured confetti and a 2/12=1/6 (0.17/17%/2:12)chance of popping the correct ballon. Each colour has an equally likely chance of getting popped.

Game rules: Step 1: Spin the colour wheel once to land on a colour

Step 2: Make a hypothesis and pop 2 balloons which you think contains that coloured confetti

Step 3: Pop these balloons and see if your hypothesis was correct

Step 4: if you pop a balloon that contains the right coloured confetti you win 10 tickets. If both your balloons had the correct colour you win 15 tickets. If both your guesses are wrong you move on to the next game.
Colour you landed on the spinner    Colour you popped first time                    Colour you popped second time

Orange                                                  Orange, Blue, Pink, Yellow                       Orange, Blue, Pink, Yellow

Yellow                                                  Orange, Blue, Pink, Yellow                       Orange, Blue, Pink, Yellow

```
  Pink                                                      Orange, Blue, Pink, Yellow                       Orange, Blue, Pink, Yellow
```

Blue                                                      Orange, Blue, Pink, Yellow                       Orange, Blue, Pink, Yellow

Possible outcomes
O,O,O    O, O, B   O, O, P    O, O, Y    O, B ,O    O, B, B   O, B, P    O, B, Y 
O,P,O    O, P, B   O, P, P    O, P, Y   O,Y,O    O, Y, B   O, Y, P    O, Y, Y

Y, Y, Y    Y, Y, O   Y, Y, B   Y, Y, P      Y, B, Y    Y, B, O   Y, B, B   Y, B, P
Y, P, Y    Y, P, O   Y, P, B   Y, P, P      Y, O, B  Y, O, P   Y, O, Y    Y, O, O

P, P, P    P, P, B    P, P, Y    P, P, O       P, O, P   P, O, O    P, O, B    P, O, Y 
P, B, P  P, B, B     P, B, Y     P, B, O      P, Y, P    P, Y, Y     P, Y, B     P, Y, O

B, B, B   B, B, P    B, B, Y     B, B, O      B, O, B    B, O, P   B, O, Y    B, O, O
B, P, B    B, P, Y    B, P, O     B, P, P      B, Y, B     B, Y, Y    B, Y, P    B, Y, O

Comment: $\frac 25\neq \frac 14$.   More to the point, the rules are unclear.  I suggest starting with the basics.  How many players?  How many colors?  Does the game end when one player hits their mark?  Worth noting:  no integer multiple of $\frac 25$ is $1$, so either the $\frac 25$ is wrong or the colors can not be equi-probable.

Comment: i made a mistake its accutally 2/8

Comment: 2/5 and 2:5 don't mean the same thing. 2/5 mean that there are 2 successes for every 5 *trials*, while 2:5 means that there are 2 successes for every 5 *failures*. So 2/5 = 2:3. And how does "educated guesses" have anything to do with this? Is there any information by which a player can make anything but a random guess?

Comment: Ok.  Mind you, that doesn't clear up the rest of the confusion.  What's the difference between "getting each color" and "landing on each color"?  If your random guesses (I assume they are random?) both fail, what does it cost?  More broadly, please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: To echo @Acccumulation, your references to "educated guesses" and "a(n) hypothesis" are very confusing.  What sort of reasoning is in play here?  How does it effect the probabilities?

Comment: ok thx for the help ill fix it and this is a school project and im not in a veryu high grade so it wont effect my grade by to much but thx again and ill fix it

Comment: Take your time.  I think people here will work with you once the rules are clear.  Note:  I don't know how to fix it since I truly can't follow the rules as you have written them.

Comment: Step 1:  Spin the color wheel once to land on a color

Step 2:  Make a hypothesis and pop 2 balloons on the board which you think contains the colour you landed on the spinner

Step 3:  Pop the balloons that you picked and see if your hypothesis was correct
It doesnt cost you anything if you lose but if you pop the correct balloon you can get a certsin amount of tickets.

Comment: ok i put the modified game rules in the comments but all i neek=d to know is if the game is fair or un fair

Comment: What does "fair" mean to you?  For math folk, "fair" would usually mean that your expected Gain/Loss should be $0$.  That is obviously not the case for your game, since you can win stuff but you can not lose anything.  So, if you mean the usual definition of "fair" then your game is unfair.  If you mean something else, you should explain further.

Comment: i modified the whole thing so pls tell me if it makes sense and you answered my question so thx

Comment: sorry but i have one more question how would i make this game fair

Comment: I still don't understand the rules so it is hard to be sure.  I don't understand the point of the spinner.  It seems that I could just name a color and then try to hit a balloon with that color.  Nor do the numbers make sense.  If I pick a balloon to pop, is there a chance that I will fail to pop it?  Is that a skill based chance?

Comment: As a general point, to make the game "fair" you have to add a charge for failing.  You use the probabilities to determine what that charge should be.  For instance, if your game is "roll a fair die.  you get $\$1$ if you roll a $6$ and you lose $\$.20$ if you roll anything else", that is fair since $1\times \frac 16-.2\times \frac 56=0$.

Comment: ok so at my school were not aloud to bring darts to throw at the board so when were playing the game the player is just going to have to pick the ballons and we will pop it

Comment: also i didnt want the spinner but everyone else in the group wants it fo some reason so the spinner has to stay

Comment: Fair: all outcomes are equally likely.

Comment: In that case, say the charge is $x$.  The probability of missing on both guesses is $\frac 9{12}\times \frac 8{11}=.\overline {54}$.  The probability of getting exactly one right is $2\times \frac 3{12}\times \frac 9{11}=.4\overline {09}$.  The probability of getting both right is $\frac 3{12}\times \frac 2{11}=.0\overline {45}$  We then have to solve for $x$ given $10\times .4\overline {09}+15\times .0\overline {45}-x\,\times .\overline {54}$ which gives $x=8.75$.

Comment: i dont understand that is there a way u can simplify it.

Comment: all i need to know if its fair or not and why these are all the possible out comes

Comment: ill post it sat the top

Comment: My game is fair (it was designed to be fair).  It is the same as yours only you lose $8.75$ tickets if both your balloons are wrong.  You can not design a fair game in which it is only possible to win but never to lose.

Comment: ok thx I'm going to go fix it but does it make sense like my math

Comment: Sorry, I really can't follow your math.  I assumed that the player is choosing (randomly) $2$ of  $12$ balloons of which three in total are "winners".  I then computed the probabilities of getting $0,1$ or $2$ winners and calculated accordingly.

Comment: I should stress: I am so unclear as to what you are doing that I am not at all sure that the variant I proposed is in keeping with what you want.  Try it out and see if it works the way you want it to.